# How to ask a number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gets

I want to make a program like,`ask a number and print 1 to number by using gets and by using loop`. So,I am asking `about gets` and how to do program `which is I given below as` **program title**.

How to ask a number by using `gets`?If possible explain me with example.

By using `gets`,I want to print `1` to `number`. My `program title`is **Ask a number and print 1 to number by using Ruby**.

How can I solve that program?Please help me on this.

Comment: I improved formatting of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arup, suggested use `Kernel#gets` to capture a user input from terminal. The remaining bit can be simply done with a for loop:

```
num = gets.to_i                    #Convert the user input to integer

for i in 1..num
  puts i
end
```

You can further modify this to suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Do as below using [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). `#gets` will give you a string, then to convert the number string to a number use [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i).

```
number = gets.to_i
```

> If I want to make program which from 1 to number then what should I do?

Use a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html) then.

```
(1..number).each do |n|
   # code
end
```

Comment: It's work for me. If I want to make program which from 1 to number then what should I do? I can't able to vote this question.

Comment: Don't understand you.. May be `(1..number) { |n| .. }`

Comment: @toro2k Yes.. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Personally I like to use `Integer()` and `rescue` the possible exception: `"a".to_i #=> 0` vs `Integer("a") #ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "a"`

Comment: @MichaelKohl Yes, that's a good suggestion although.

Comment: @ArupRakshit : I am fully understand your answer. It's perfect answer.